# error TS2314: Generic type 'Component<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In using ReactJS with TypeScript, this error comes up:

`error TS2314: Generic type 'Component<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `P` is the props type and the `S` is the state type. You'll want to change:

> `class MyComponent extends React.Component { ...`

to:

```
interface MyProps {}
interface MyState {}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> { ...
```

Then expand the `MyProps` and `MyState` interfaces to include typing for all the props and state that the component needs.

Comment: extends React.Component<P, {}>