# TSC command error TS2314 on lib.d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, tsc

I'm trying to run the TSC command on **WebStorm** but every time I do I get this error :

> AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(1378,151):
>   error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise' requires 2 type
>   argument(s).

My project works fine though. I'm new to this, can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error TS2314: Generic type 'Component<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506180/error-ts2314-generic-type-componentp-s-requires-2-type-arguments)

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you're using a Promise?

Comment: @Aron Promise is being used in the lib.d.ts file. I hjavent used it myself. 
and it's everywhere in that file. here's a line from it : 

  then(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => T | PromiseLike<T>) | undefined | null): Promise<T>;

Comment: @OlegEstekhin nope, that didnt help me.

Comment: what do you mean by running tsc on webstorm? what do you do exactly?